# How to call <div> on submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

- Please refer code below i m learning jquery and i want to display 
   tag named **#child** on submit button click using javascript/jquery can any one help me how to call  on button click
- And also want  to call #**child and #home**    tag on >>(next button) & <<(prev button)** on button click respectively in code >> and<< is written as  &lt and &glt.? can anyone
  help me out ?

  ```
          <div data-role="page" id="home">
              <div data-theme="d" data-role="header">
                  <h3>
                      The Grand Bhagvati
                  </h3>
                  <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" href="#home">
                      &lt;&lt;
                  </a>
                  <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="fade" href="#child">
                      &gt;&gt;
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div data-role="content">
                  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                          <label for="textinput1">
                              User:
                          </label>
                          <input id="textinput1" placeholder="Khushu" type="text" />
                      </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  <input data-theme="d" ="submitbtn" value="Login" type="submit"  onSubmit="redirect()"/>
              </div>
              <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
                  <h3>
                      Page1
                  </h3>

                  </div>
          </div>
  ```

  ```
          <div data-role="page" id="child">
              <div data-theme="d" data-role="header">
                  <h3>
                      The Grand Bhagvati
                  </h3>
                  <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" >
                      &lt;&lt;
                  </a>
                  <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="fade" >
                      &gt;&gt;
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div data-role="content">
                  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                          <label for="textinput1">
                              User:
                          </label>
                          <input id="textinput1" placeholder="Khushu" type="text" />
                      </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  <input data-theme="d" value="Login" type="submit"  onsubmit="redirect()"/>
              </div>
              <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
                  <h3>
                      Page1
                  </h3>

                  </div>
          </div>
  ```

Comment: what do you mean by "call #child and #home tag"? Call it to do what?

Comment: i just tried make my question clear and formatted it

Comment: it is <div id = child> & <div id = home>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a tag use

```
$('#child').show();  // where child is the id of the element
```

and to hide ...

```
$('#child').hide();
```

alternatively, you can simply toggle it between hide/show as follows:

```
$('#child').toggle();
```

to attach these to an onclick event of a button ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonID').click(function() {
        $('#child').toggle();
    });
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: do u want me to make javascript function

Comment: yeah it will need to be in a js function which is called via a button or some other control

Comment: but it is not working i m using it on click as follow:               <input data-theme="d" value="Login" type="submit"  onclick="redirect()"/>

Comment: have you added the jQuery library?

Comment: now when i displaying child div my jquery theme (data-theme="a") do not work in child div. can any 1 help me?

Answer (score 0):

The below code is for javascript

`var Home= document.getElementById("home");`

```
Home.style.display="none";//To hide the div
Home.style.display="";//To display the div
```

Comment: That's a very confusing answer. Your variable 'divid' is misleading, as document.getElementById() returns the object. Further, divid.style.display="" will set the display property to inline, where divs are naturally block elements, so the code should be divid.style.display="block"

Comment: @gwynhowell divid in this case is "home" and "child"

Comment: @gwynhowell display="block" will also work in some browsers it creates some compatiblity issues

Comment: which browsers? I know some older versions of firefox didn't respond to display='inline', so you had to use display='' instead. but i am not aware of display='block' having compatibility issues?

Comment: now when i displaying child div my jquery theme (data-theme="a") do not work in child div.                                             can any one of u help me